# Find non-negative integers $n$ such that $9^n + 1$ is divisible by 365

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, divisibility

For which non-negative integers $n$ is $9^n + 1$ is divisible by 365?

First approach:
$365 = 5 * 73 \implies 9^n + 1 \equiv (-1)^n + 1 \equiv 0 \; \text{(mod 5)} \Leftrightarrow n = 2k + 1$

So $n$ must be odd. Thus $9^{2k+1} + 1 \equiv 0 \; \text{(mod 73)}$

Unfortunately checking all residues (mod 73) isn‘t an option… How would you proceed from this/is there a better approach?

Comment: It is false for odd numbers in general. $9^5+1 \equiv 66\bmod 73$. But $9^{3^n}+1\equiv 0\bmod 73$.

Comment: The powers of $9$ will be periodic $\pmod {73}$ with a period that divides $\phi(73)=72$  It is not unreasonable at all to start multiplying up $\pmod {73}$ and look for the period.  It is quick.

Comment: So checking for the period by calculating $9^t + 1$ (mod 73) for t = 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, … would be an approach? How would you do that by hand?

Comment: The period seems to be (0, 66, 10, 0, 66, 10, 0, …) starting with $t=3$. Therefore all odd multiples of 3 should be the solution, i.e. $n = 6z + 3$ for all non-negative $z$

Comment: $73|9^3+1=(9+1)(9^2-9+1)$

Answer (score 1):

You can note that $9\cdot 8 = 72 \equiv -1 \pmod{73}.$ So you know that $-8$ is the inverse of $9 \pmod{73}$.  Then notice that $9^2 = 81 \equiv 8 \pmod{73}.$ So $-9^2$ is the inverse of $9 \pmod{73}$.  Therefore $9^3\equiv -1 \pmod{73}$ and $9^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{73}.$  Then $9^{6k+3} \equiv -1 \pmod{73}.$